# Exposing data in an atom feed

Tags: feed, atom-feed

How do I add extra data into an atom feed that does not map into the standard entry nodes (title, link, id, updated, summary)? Is it possible to add my own custom xml here and still be compliant with the spec?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several different ways documented at http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/atom-format-spec.php#extending_atom.

You can add [extension elements](http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/atom-format-spec.php#extension) at the end of your [atom:entry](http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/atom-format-spec.php#element.entry).

```
<atom:entry>
   <!--- all the normal stuff --->
   <mything:Thing xmlns:mything="http://example.com/example.xsd">
      <!--- whatever --->
   </mything:Thing>
</atom:entry>
```